# Use a foreach loop within a foreach loop in a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I am wondering on how to do the following. I have the Linq query:

```
Items items.Where(i => i.GetType() == typeof(SubItem))
                .Cast<SubItem>()
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(i => i.SomeList.Add(i.SomeObject.ForEach(i => i.SomeString)));
```

My question is about `i.SomeList.Add()`. I want to return a couple of string values to `i.SomeList.Add()` from `i.SomeObject` but I do not know how I can do this in this way? Is it even possible like this to have another ForEach Loop within a Linq ForEach usinq Linq query?

Comment: `ForEach` is a List method, not LINQ. LINQ is a **query** language. Why use it at all if you want nested loops?

Comment: `ForEach` is absolutely wrong here as are `Cast`, `i.GetType() == typeof(SubItem)`, and `ToList`

Comment: `.Where(i => i.GetType() == typeof(SubItem)).Cast<SubItem>()` is equivalent to `OfType<SubIttem>()`. What are you trying to do anyway? `ForEach` doesn't return anything, so `i.SomeArray.Add(i.SomeObject.ForEach` won't even compile. Whatever you want to do, it's far easier to do with simple loops

Comment: Maybe you want `i.SomeArray.AddRange(i.SomeObject.Select(x => x.SomeString))` though that only works if `SomeArray` is a `List<T>` and not an array as the name implies.

Comment: It is a List<T> I will correct that, so what you all basically mean is that I should use a simple Foreach loop to achieve above? I tried to be concise, that is why I tried to use Linq for that.

Comment: What is wrong with using ForEach as well as Cast and GetType and ToList in this way?

Comment: `GetType()` is slow and will miss any types that derive from `SubItem`. `ToList` isn't necessarily wrong but it's confusing here and people often use it without thinking. Instead use `foreach (var item in items.OfType<SubItem>()) {...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this `foreach` loop will achieve your goal, if I've understood the problem.

It will loop over any element of `items` that is a (or is derived from) `SubItem`. It will then select all `SomeObject.SomeString` strings and add them to the `SomeList`.

```
foreach (var subItem in items.OfType<SubItem>()) {
    subItem.SomeList.AddRange(subItem.SomeObject.Select(o => o.SomeString));
}
```

This is a compilation of suggestions from Panagiotis Kanavos, juharr, and Aluan Haddad.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ isn't really for running `Add` operations... it's much more powerful when you think of it as returning a resultset.

So instead of

```
//Add every value of SomeField to targetList
sourceList.ForEach( x => targetList.Add(x.SomeField) )
```

Think of doing it this way:

```
//Create a list of all instances of SomeField and assign it to targetList
targetList = sourceList.Select( x => x.SomeField).ToList();
```

Or if you need to keep the existing items in the target list, do this:

```
//Create a list of all SomeFields and add it to targetList
targetList.AddRange
(
     sourceList.Select( x => x.SomeField )
);
```

Similarly, instead of using a nested foreach, consider using `SelectMany`.

I'm not completely clear on your requirements but you probably want something like this:

```
//To SomeList, add the SomeString field from all instances of SomeObject
someList.AddRange
(
    items.OfType<SubItem>().SelectMany( x => x.SomeObject ).Select( x => x.SomeString )
);
```